# jquery how to load different scripts when i click on different links?

Tags: jquery

i have a list:

```
<select name="test" id="test">
<option value="1">about</option>
<option value="2">portfolio</option>
</select>
```

what i am trying to do is to load a different script inside a div `#content` depending on what option i choose. The script will load some rss content:

```
<div id="content">      
<script id="1" type="text/javascript" src="http://rss.bloople.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.exploretalent.com%2Frss_cj.php%3Fpid%3D3087968%26file_xml%3Dcastings_new.xml&showtitle=false&type=js&id=1307038796890991"></script>
<script id="2" type="text/javascript" src="http://rss.bloople.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.exploretalent.com%2Frss_cj.php%3Fpid%3D3087968%26file_xml%3Dcastings_new.xml&showtitle=false&type=js&id=1307038796890991"></script>
</div>
```

lets say if i select option `1` then a script with id `1` will load into page, if i select option `2` than the script with id `1` will unload and `2` will load

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: manipulate with : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: i think adding `id` to script is not a good idea.  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script) is not mentioned that id is valid attribute for `script`

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
<select name="test" id="test">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">about</option>
    <option value="2">portfolio</option>
</select>

<div id="feed-1307038796890991"></div>
```

and the js

```
$(function(){
    var urls = [
        "http://rss.bloople.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.exploretalent.com%2Frss_cj.php%3Fpid%3D3087968%26file_xml%3Dcastings_new.xml&showtitle=false&type=js&id=1307038796890991",
        "http://rss.bloople.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.exploretalent.com%2Frss_cj.php%3Fpid%3D3087968%26file_xml%3Dcastings_new.xml&showtitle=false&type=js&id=1307038796890991"
        ];

    $("#test").change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != ""){
            $.getScript(urls[$(this).val() - 1]);
        }
    })
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vLzCU/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a jQuery [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event to the option elements, and have that click event call a jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) event.

It might look something like:

```
$('test').children()[0].click(function() {
  $('#resultDiv').load('yourLink.html');
});
```

Comment: well, my only problem is that i will have 50 `<script id="...">`. and i don't want to create 50 html pages

Answer (score 0):

u Must see below dynamic javascript loader js library

### [headjs](http://headjs.com/)

OR

### [labjs](http://labjs.com/)